# Magento 2: Install Doofinder

Tags: magento2, module, installation

I'm trying to install Doofinder on Magento 2 but the Readiness Check launch a lot of errors.

[image]

does anyone know the requirements for each case to install doofinder?

Thanks!!

Comment: please follow two link :- 1> https://www.doofinder.com/en/blog/installation-configuration-doofinder-in-magento .2 > https://github.com/doofinder/doofinder-magento2 may help you

Comment: Seems like you are missing basic magento2 requirements as some php extensions, crons, etc, also check here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html